# How to convert DatetimeIndex to a string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I'm dealing with OHLC data of a stock and I have set 'date' column as index. Output of certain expression is:

`DatetimeIndex(['2021-08-30 03:45:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='time', freq=None)`

I want to grab just the part `'2021-08-30 03:45:00+00:00'` as a string. How do I do it?

I tried `str()` but it didn't work.

I'm a beginner in python/pandas. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank You.

Comment: `str(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-08-30 03:45:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='time', freq=None)[0])`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much:)

Comment: `.format()` is also useful